# How to save database operation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Thanks for watching my first question.
I have something confused.
How could I write the operations of database  into database and don't write the function in every Controller?
I have considered middleware and find that must change my route register style.
my Route is this:

```
Route:resource('province','\\Modules\\Info\\Controllers\\P_ProvinceController');
```

Dose it has some awesome methods replace this?

```
 public function Store(Request $request)
        {
            $params = $request->input('data');
            $params['CreateID'] = Auth::user()->id;
            $params['CreateName'] = Auth::user()->name;
            $params['CreateTime'] = Carbon::now();
            $province = P_ProvinceModel::Create($params);
            $params['Pro_Is_Del'] = 1;
            $log_info['table'] = $province->getTable();
            $log_info['type']  = "create";
            $log_info['user']  = Auth::user()->name;
            $log_info['datetime'] =  Carbon::now();
            LogModel::create($log_info);
            if($province){
                return response()->json(array(
                    'status' => 200,
                    'msg' => '新增成功',
                    'data' => $province
                ));
            }else
                return response()->json(array(
                    'status' => 500,
                    'msg' => '保存失败',
                ));

        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Laravel Have a function called as `save()` and more information can be found at https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch and many more laravel related video tutorials available for free and few are paid.

Comment: I can save the result into the database By LogModel::create() Method. I don't wanna write the method in every Controller . Because I have write many Controller already. How could i finish it without modify every Controller..

Comment: Then what is the problem.

Comment: Check out my answer below. I had an issue when saving records that I needed to know the creator/updator. I added 2 "observers".CreatedBy and UpdatedBy observers. In each model I want the authors to be known I simply add the trait to that particular model and viola. Whenever it is saved the authors are updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved across model functionality

First Create a Trait that does what you want on save.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Observers;

trait CreatedByObserver
{
    public static function bootCreatedByObserver(){
        /** Simply means that whenever this model is creating a model do: */
        static::creating(function($model){
            if(auth()->check()){
                 $responsiblePerson = auth()->user()->first_name . " " . auth()->user()->last_name;
            } else {
                 $responsiblePerson = "system";
            }
            /** You can set any model variables within */
            $model->created_by = $responsiblePerson;
        });
    }
}
```

In there do all you need to do when a record is saved/created/updated/deleted

Then In all Models you want this behaviour used add the trait.

Check them out here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#events

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will try it now

Comment: @wtySk If this worked please mark as correct. Could do with some rep

Comment: sorry about that :) I just understand how to use trait in the Class. I put the static function in every Model and it works! lol~.thanks for your rapid exact answer help me finish the question. @Chris And thanks the others.

Comment: @wtySk If you want to use the trait in the class right under the `class ClassName {` Add `use \My\Traits\AuditTrait;`

Answer (score 0):

As far i understand your question, you are asking for way to make your controller an abstract type, i.e. controller just need to handle the route and view not any other things(like database,application logic etc) which is the philosophy of the laravel Framework.

To make your controller abstract (meaning of abstract as explained aboave),
first you need to understand, **"What your application logic are and what your database logic are ?"** 
when you understand these two things then, you can easily separate your aapplication logic and databasse logic from your controller.

For example :
For keeping your Application logic you can make `service` folder in your root of your project also you can make folder name 'Dao' (Database access object) in the same path of `service` . You need to keep these folder in autoload from your composer. Just make class for service and your Dao.

And now your application follow will be, 
First Route, will hit controller then controller will need to call some method in `service` and then service will call the respective `DAO` . method.

Example :

**Controller/YourController.php**

```
Class YourController extends Controller {

 public function Store(Request $request,yourservice,$yourService)
        {
        $this->myservice = $yourservice;
        $this->myservice->store('your inputs request');
return $something ;
}


}
```

**service/yourService.php**

```
    Class yourService {

    public function store($yourinputs,yourDao $mydao){

     $this->mydao = $mydao;

//you can use your application logic here 
    return $this->mydao->create($yourinputs);
    }
```

And now the turn is for `DAO` :

**dao/yourdao.php**

```
use model // use your model here .
    class yourDao {
       public function create($yourdata,yourmodel $model){
       $this->model = $model;
      return $this->model->create($yourdata);

}
    }
```

Now,  you can see the controller just save the data in database, but don't know how it is saving the data and what are the application logic. 
This explanation is just a simple way of doing project to make a controller abstract. There are other various ways of doing this. For example you can see [Repository Design Pattern](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-repository-design-pattern--net-35804) , which also used by laravel core .

Hope this explanation will not bore anyone . :) Happy coding .